# PHP Javascript page loads twice

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

I have written this small site, with registration and everything, and I got to a point I think I am not too sure what is happening.
It first started as the DB reporting to me that the user I am trying to write into the DB has a duplicate entry (where it should be unique), which really puzzled me, how can it be that I have duplicate ? Well. It took me three days to realize that the page is being somehow called twice !

I put a

> $_SESSION['one']=0;

and a

> $_SESSION['two']=0;

in the topmost and bottommost parts of the page accordingly.
then I changed them both to `++`, so I can check how many times they have been passed through.

I used the verification link from the emaill the site has sent, and tested their values.

Strangely enough, `'one' would equal 2 and 'two' would equal 1`...

This explains exactly why all worked registration-wise, but I got all those errors about those duplicates.
Though, I used firebug to trace any redirections, but couldn't see anything...
It shows the page has 12 GETs and a POST. 
I was hoping to bump into a redirect and debug accordingly, but alas, or maybe I don't know how to use firebug to trace these redirects...

I would appreciate any suggestion
Thanks in advance!

Comment: since you are using firebug if you open the "Net" tab and refresh the page using the reload button, does it load the "Net" tab and then reloads it again?

Comment: I would suggest showing some more code..?

Comment: If you put button inside a, browser will send 2 request to the server when you click on the button. Maybe it closes connection for the first request, which is the reason the 'two' is not incremented.

Comment: Impossible to answer without understanding your registration structure and process, We need to know if you use OO and so on...

Comment: Unrelated, but if you have duplicate entries in your db, then you need to re design your schema. Use keys to prevent dups.

Comment: @jeffreydev, This is home network and happens quite fast but seems like the Net tab reloads after the page.

Comment: @Darhazer, I wasn't very clear about what you said, but what happens, is a page being loaded, apparently twice, are you suggesting to put a button on the page and see if there are two requests ? Something inside the code is causing that, and are you saying that the connection may have been closed by the DB ? I am happening to use tranactions, but I can harldy see any reason (although tested already)...

Comment: @sciritai, I do have keys. What happens is that I get a second run on which I get to see my debugging log, which says it couldn't execute because of a duplicate (from the first run).

Comment: @Ted I'm saying that if you have &lt;a&gt;&lt;button/&gt;&lt;/a&gt; when you click it, browser will send 2 request, closing the connection for the first one at some point. Anyway, this is 1 of possible issues, without some code we can only guess

Comment: @Ted I've had exactly the same problem, what I do to fix it is change my doctype to html 5 <!DOCTYPE html> and then validate the page using w3c validator, this problem was only occuring for my in firefox using firebug.

Comment: @jeffreydev!, it seems to work... I don't know if I should be happy or cry, but it took me around 4 days.... How did you find that solution ?

Comment: By allot of testing :) drove my crazy as well, I think it's a firebug bug, ill make a proper answer out of it so people who have the same problem don't have to read through the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, here is the answer that worked for me and Ted:

What I do to fix it is change my doctype to html 5  and then validate the page using w3c validator, this problem was only occurring for my in firefox using firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some `<img>` or `<script>` with `src=""`? Or maybe some `<link>` stylesheet with empty `href`?

Is firebug showing you, in net tab, that your site is called twice?

Comment: I am in the process of checking why the page loads twice, I am not too sure how to see it with firebug, it seems like the page was loaded twice in php, if it was for javascript then I would have known that through firebug right ?

Comment: No, doesn't show that it loads twice, but I am sure php is running it twice. Are these empty links prone of reloading the page btw ?

Comment: Those empty links just load the page once more as an image, script or link if this page is a index.php. If you haven't it in firebug net tab, so my answer won't help you. If it possible make some online wersion of your script OR pase code in your question OR try to comment some fragments of code and repeat situation - you should figure what fragment do this, and then maybe we can help you:)

Comment: look up @jeffreydev solution, this is scary

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issues usually happen when you have a fatal or otherwise unignorable error that forces PHP to terminate you script early, in the midst of processing a request.

Check you error log for details of happening.

Answer (score 0):

It is Firebug that is causing the page to load twice. Apparently changing the doctype to html5
as:

instead of html4 has overridden that bug.
When you are going to deploy your site, go back to html 4, and of course, always keep the server safe from such bugs. Use DB constraints, validation and escaping when needed.
Hope this helps, and Big thanks to @jeffreydev!!